# How to make a layout with only aboslute positioning in pyqt

Tags: layout, pyqt, drag-and-drop, position

I want to make a layout where the user is able to move the widget inside freely with no constraints of rows or column. So I'm using absolute positioning. I'm able to make it happen in a window with no layout but I don't know what to use as a layout , problem is in the commented line in the code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication,QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


class DragLabel(QLabel):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.label = DragLabel('first', self)
        self.label2 = DragLabel('second', self)
        self.label3 = DragLabel('third', self)

        self.label.move(50, 50)
        self.label2.move(100, 100)
        self.label3.move(150, 150)

        # self.main_frame=QHBoxLayout()
        # self.classic_frame=QVBoxLayout()
        #what should I use here to make a frame working with absolute position only
        # self.absolute_frame = ???
        # self.absolute_frame.addWidget(self.label)
        # self.absolute_frame.addWidget(self.label2)
        # self.absolute_frame.addWidget(self.label3)
        # self.main_frame.addLayout(self.classic_frame)
        # self.main_frame.addLayout(self.absolute_frame)   
        # self.setLayout(self.main_frame)


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        widget = e.source()
        if isinstance(widget,DragLabel):
            e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        pos = e.pos()
        widget_dep = e.source()

        if isinstance(widget_dep,DragLabel):
            widget_dep_name = widget_dep.text()
            print(widget_dep_name)
            widget_dep.move(pos.x(),pos.y())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: They are called "layout managers" because they *manage the layout*. If you want to allow the user to freely move widgets, those widgets must *not* be added to a layout.

Comment: @musicamante but if i want to allow the user to freely move widget in part of a window but not the whole window ?

Comment: Then don't add those widgets to the layout, just create them with the parent and user spacer items as placeholders.